# How do I get system time in millisecond in C++ (not since epoch)?

Tags: c++, c++11, time, c++-chrono, milliseconds

I would like to get the current **milliseconds of the system clock**, in C++ (on Linux OS).

What I want is the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds of the system clock. I have been able to obtain the hours, minutes and seconds, with the following code:

```
chrono::system_clock::time_point currentTime = chono::system_clock::now();
time_t currentTime_c = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(currentTime);
cout<<"Current time is: "<<put_time(localtime(&currentTime_c), "%T");
```

However, I have not been able to find how can I obtain the milliseconds of the system.

Just to clarify, I have seen people using chrono::duration to measure the milliseconds between time points in the software but this is **not** what I want. I want the milliseconds of the system clock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a line:

```
auto msec = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(currentTime - chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(currentTime_c));
```

Alternatively:

```
auto msec2 = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(currentTime.time_since_epoch()) % 1000;
```

Comment: I think your first is best because it doesn't introduce a type cast (i.e. `.time_since_epoch()`), and because it doesn't have any explicit conversion factors (i.e. `1000`).

Comment: I used the first one and it works great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this

```
using namespace std::chrono;
milliseconds ms = duration_cast< milliseconds >(
    system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
);
```